# Set as Ringtone Android requires double click

Tags: android, methods, ringtone

I got this code:
`

```
protected void setRingtone() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Boolean success = false;
        sound = new File(folder, "Ilidan.mp3");
        if (!sound.exists()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Ilidan " + folder.toString());
            try {
                InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ilidan);
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(sound.getPath());
                byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
                int read = 0;

            try {
                while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buff, 0, read);
                }
            } finally {
                in.close();

                out.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            success = false;
            Log.i(TAG, "Ne da radi.");
        }
    } else {
        success = true;
        Log.i(TAG, "VEc postoji.");
    }

    if (!success) {
        onSetRingtoneError("There was issue writting file.");
    } else {
        setSettingsRingtone();
    }
}

private void onSetRingtoneError(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Nije Radilo ", 5000).show();

}

private void setSettingsRingtone() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, sound.getAbsolutePath());
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "Alert");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/*");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, R.string.app_name);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, true);

    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(sound.getAbsolutePath());
    getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + sound.getAbsolutePath() + "\"",
            null);
    Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
            MainActivity.this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
            newUri);


}

{

}
```

But here is what happens. When I click on button first time, it creates file only, second time when I click it sets as ringtone.
What  am I doing wrong? How can I make my app to copy file and set it as ringtone in 1 click?

Comment: just see my ans :) its a small mistake dude :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   protected void setRingtone() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Boolean success = false;
            sound = new File(folder, "Ilidan.mp3");
            if (!sound.exists()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Ilidan " + folder.toString());
                try {
                    InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ilidan);
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(sound.getPath());
                    byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
                    int read = 0;

                try {
                    while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
                        out.write(buff, 0, read);
                    }
                } finally {
                    in.close();
                     out.close();
                     success = true;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                success = false;
                Log.i(TAG, "Ne da radi.");
            }
        } else {
            success = true;
            Log.i(TAG, "VEc postoji.");
        }

        if (!success) {
            onSetRingtoneError("There was issue writting file.");
        } else {
            setSettingsRingtone();
        }
    }

    private void onSetRingtoneError(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Nije Radilo ", 5000).show();

    }

    private void setSettingsRingtone() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, sound.getAbsolutePath());
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "Alert");
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/*");
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, R.string.app_name);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, true);

        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(sound.getAbsolutePath());
        getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + sound.getAbsolutePath() + "\"",
                null);
        Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                MainActivity.this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
                newUri);


    }

    {

    }
```

i just change your finally like

```
 finally {
                in.close();
                 out.close();
                 success = true;
            }
```

coz first time only create folder and success boolean is false then next time it will be true so just update your finally

Comment: u can also update your sucess=true; in try block also wd chk  if (!sound.exists()) i.e u will 100% sure that file make successfully

Comment: O yeah I didn't notice that. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

After creating the file `if(!sound.exists())`  you should set success to true

```
success = true;
```

In your action , you declared afile , then you tested it (if exists or not ) , if (!exists) , you create the file , but you forget to set  success to true,

```
//your code
finally {
                in.close();
                 out.close();
                 success = true;
            }
```